# repeated failure of wireless printer access (Windows, HP Printer)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, printer

I have Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362 Build 18362

I have an HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M277dw. This is configured to be "wireless printing", with "wi-fi direct" and "hp eprint" both turned off. When I tap on the wireless printing icon on the printer screen, I get Status Ready, wireless on, cable disconnected (there are no communication cables plugged into the printer), and the SSID of my 5g network.

I am using Google's wireless network hubs; I have one on the same desk top as the printer, and it's plugged into the LinkSys EA6350 for network access (I turned off the EA6350's wirelesss since I didn't need it any more).

The various devices throughout the house and just outside all connect to the 5g network with no problem (I had to upgrade when I got the Tesla). From the above status screen, it appears that the printer is also connected to my 5g network. I have entered the passphrase through the printer touchscreen, etc.

What normally happens is that I attempt to print and am told there is "an error". I can't find an error message anywhere. Sometimes if I reboot the printer it works; sometimes if I reboot the printer and the computer it works;  one recent time it worked after I re-installed the drivers for the printer.

What can I do to toubleshoot this? I don't see why, after it has worked, that a few days later it doesn't work when no configuration has changed. I reboot the computer (a laptop) fairly frequently, but not the printer. I have travelled some with the laptop, then come home, but don't see why that should cause the printing (and nothing else about the network) to fail.

Ideas?

Comment: Note that 5G is not a WiFi protocol. I have found that WiFi can be troublesome for printers. Have you tried connecting it with an RJ45 (ethernet) cable to the Linksys?

Comment: @hdhondt I want to be able to print from laptops that have no wired connection, and I'm no longer using the LinkSys for my home wireless network. The wireless networks seem to have slower and faster; I named the faster one 5g just to distinguish them. Is there some way to figure out what's wrong with the wireless network printing, which is one of the reasons I bought the printer, and which used to work?

Comment: As long as the Linksys router is still on the network, the WiFi PCs should be able to access the printer. Alternatively, I believe the Google hub also has 2 RJ45 ports.

Comment: @hdhondt well, they can't access the network. The LinkSys router is still in, but not its wireless part (I've got other things plugged into it) The Google Hub does have another rj45 port, but I'm not sure how that helps me. I've read that a PC must be "on the same network" to access the printer; I don't know whether plugged-in is the same as wireless. I can try combinations, but find it irritating that I'm left with trial-and-error when there is a solution someone knowledgeable could reason out frontwards instead. I think I'll try renaming the Google network and starting over. Tomorrow.

Comment: The RJ45 and WiFi in the hub are on the same subnet. If the printer connect via RJ45 it will be on the same network as the WiFi PCs.

Comment: Thanks - that's the sort of thing that's useful to know. I'll add "connect printer to hub with cat5" to my list of options to try.